# ViewModelProviders устарел, чем нужно заменить?

Tags: android, kotlin

Я использую ViewModelProviders. Но сегодня обновив библиотеки появилось 30 сообщений. Как я понял ViewModelProviders стал более не доступен и его нужно заменить, посмотрел в developer.google но так и не понял на что нужно заменить ?
Мой код:

```
**
 * Kotlin extensions for dependency injection
 */

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> FragmentActivity.injectViewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)[T::class.java]
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.injectViewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)[T::class.java]
}
```

и можете объяснить, почему он устарел ?

Comment: в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html) сказано, что заменить [на этот](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.html)

Comment: Создавайте `ViewModelProvider` с помощью конструктора напрямую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ с

> stackoverflow.com

As per the documentation:

> Use the by viewModels() Kotlin property delegate or
>   ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner, Factory),
>   passing in the fragment and factory.

So you can replace your extensions with:

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> FragmentActivity.injectViewModel(factory:  ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[T::class.java]
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.injectViewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[T::class.java]
}
```

And, as per the error message, you can instead use the Kotlin property extensions in the fragment-ktx and activity-ktx dependencies and remove your extension methods entirely.

Namely, by viewModels and by activityViewModels for Fragments:

```
// Retrieve the ViewModel associated with this Fragment
val viewModel: MyVewModel by viewModels { myFactory }

// Retrieve the ViewModel associated with the activity
val activityViewModel: MyVewModel by activityViewModels { myFactory }
```

Or, if you're accessing the ViewModel from your Activity itself, you'd use its by viewModels:

```
// In an Activity, you can retrieve a ViewModel scoped to the Activity
// by using viewModels
val viewModel: MyVewModel by viewModels { myFactory }
```